# The nickname in comments is not updated

Tags: support, user-profile

[Why are there only 12 Wii Demos?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15616/why-are-there-only-12-wii-demos#comment-21273)

My previous nickname was 0101, I do know it's not just text, because I get alert if some writes @myNickName

P.S. I like to change nicknames once in a while and it's not a BIG bug, just saying.

Answer (score 1):

The page now shows your updated nickname. Usually those fields are cached and need some time to update.

Comment: I should have followed the link, I thought he meant @user stuff in comments.

Comment: @Fabian Oh, yeah, that's just text to the server and can't be updated

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is just text. It is not a special name type object, but a set of string comparisons done against all display names at the time of submission/edit. You can check the full details on [comment reply rules here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020). So in being just plain comment text, it's not a dynamic entry that can just update when your profile changes.

Text update would have a chance for making exceptionally awkward addresses if the reply wasn't the full name, which is common for many users who use names with spaces. `@Grace Note` is used to refer to me often, but only the `@Grace` actually triggers a reply. If I were to, say, change my name to `Diamond Wedding`, then all those replies would end up reading as `@DiamondWedding Note`.